# ¿Por que no funciona la barra de navegación en el teléfono?

Tags: html, css

**Edito** pues como dijo Alvaro Montoro, se terminó el enlace que cree para mostrar mi error, pero con el código se pudo resolver.
Hola estoy creando esta web, no sin la ayuda de todos, y funciona en local perfectamente.
La he subido a un servidor y al probar como funciona en el teléfono, me encuentro que la barra de navegación no se queda fija y el botón que aparece para acceder al los elementos de esta barra, no funciona. 
En el ordenador funciona.
El problema llega con el dispositivo móvil. En el que no se ve el botón de enlaces de la barra de navegación.
Dejo el código html que espero sea donde esté el problema.

¿ Habría forma de arreglar esto ?
**Edite el código** Gracias

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,700,900);
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ek+Mukta:400,600,700');
*{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

html nav.navbar.navbar-custom{
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Ek Mukta', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
    color: #666;
    background-color: #fff;
 font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
 font-weight: 400;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

h1 {
 font-size: 38px;
}
h2 {
 font-size: 36px;
}
h3 {
 font-size: 32px;
}
h4 {
 font-size: 28px;
}
h5 {
 font-size: 24px;
}
h6 {
 font-size: 20px;
}

h1,
h2,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
 color: #111;
}

h3{
 margin: 0 0 30px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
 color: #008000 !important;
}

h1.h-xlight,h2.h-xlight,h3.h-xlight ,h4.h-xlight ,h5.h-xlight ,h6.h-xlight  {
 font-weight: 200;
}

h1.h-light,h2.h-light,h3.h-light ,h4.h-light ,h5.h-light ,h6.h-light  {
 font-weight: 300;
}

h1.h-bold,h2.h-bold,h3.h-bold ,h4.h-bold ,h5.h-bold ,h6.h-bold  {
 font-weight: 600;
}

h1.font-light,h2.font-light,h3.font-light,h4.font-light,h5.font-light,h6.font-light {
 color: #fff;
}

.big-heading {
 font-size: 48px;
 font-weight: 700;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 10px;

}

.text-center{
 font-size: 20px;
 
}

.service-desc p{
 font-size: 16px;
}

p.lead {
 font-weight: 600;
}

.highlight-light {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
 padding: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #111;
}

.highlight-dark {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 padding: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
 color: #fff;
}

.highlight-color {
 padding: 20px;
 display: inline-block;
}

a {
    color: #666;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

blockquote {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #999;
}

blockquote.bg-light {
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
 padding: 20px;
 color: #222;
}

blockquote.bg-dark {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 padding: 20px;
}

blockquote strong {
  font-weight: 700;
}




.light {
    font-weight: 400;
}
.site-logo {
 display: flex;
}
.site-logo a.brand {
 color: #111;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-size: 32px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 900;
 margin-top: 20px;
}

#navigation {
 background: #fff;
 z-index: 9999;
 width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.navbar {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.navbar-brand {
    font-weight: 700;
}


.navbar-brand:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse .nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}


.navbar-custom ul.nav li a {
 font-size: 16px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #444;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav li a {
     -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 color: #fff;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu {
   border-radius: 0; 
 margin-top: 21px;
 border-top: none;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav li a:hover ul.dropdown-menu {
     -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}


.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f5f5;

}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li:last-child{
 border-bottom: none;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
 padding: 10px 20px;
}

.navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover {
 background: #fefefe;
}

.navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li a {
 color: #666;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a {
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

.navbar-toggle {
    padding: 4px 6px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-toggle:active {
    outline: 0;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

hr.bold {
  border-top: 3px solid #eee;
}

.divider-header {
 display: block;
 width: 40px;
 height: 2px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.divider-short {
 display: block;
 width: 60px;
 height: 5px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* margins */
.marginbot-0{margin-bottom:0 !important;}
.marginbot-10{margin-bottom:10px !important;}
.marginbot-20{margin-bottom:20px !important;}
.marginbot-30{margin-bottom:30px !important;}
.marginbot-40{margin-bottom:40px !important;}
.marginbot-50{margin-bottom:50px !important;}
.marginbot-60{margin-bottom:60px !important;}
.marginbot-70{margin-bottom:70px !important;}
.marginbot-80{margin-bottom:80px !important;}
.marginbot-90{margin-bottom:90px !important;}
.marginbot-100{margin-bottom:100px !important;}

.margintop-0{margin-top:0 !important;}
.margintop-10{margin-top:10px !important;}
.margintop-20{margin-top:20px !important;}
.margintop-30{margin-top:30px !important;}
.margintop-40{margin-top:40px !important;}
.margintop-45{margin-top:45px !important;}
.margintop-50{margin-top:50px !important;}


#container-2{
 background-color: #EBB250;
}
.home-section {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
 display:block;
    position:relative;
 z-index:120;
 
}
.home-section2 {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
 display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:120;
}

.inner-section {
    padding-top: 110px;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
}


.home-section.nopadd-bot {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}


.section-heading h2 {
 font-size: 24px;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.section-heading p {
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 1.6em;
}

.color-dark .section-heading h2 {
 color: #111;
}
.color-dark .section-heading p {
 color: #444;
}

.color-dark .divider-short {
 background: #666;
}
.color-dark .divider-header {
 background: #666;
}

.color-light .divider-short {
 background: #666;
}
.color-light .divider-header {
 background: #666;
}


.color-light .section-heading h2 {
 color: #fff;
}
.color-light .section-heading p {
 color: #fefefe;
}

.color-light blockquote,.color-light p {
 color: #fefefe;
}


.bg-white {
 background: #fff;
}

.bg-gray {
 background: #f9f9f9;
}


.bg-dark {
 background: #404040;
}


.text-light {
 color: #fff;
}

.intro {
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 padding:0;
}
.intro-inner {
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
 padding:120px 0 20px;
}

.brand-heading {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.intro-text {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 650px;
}

.carousel-control {
    width: 0;
}

.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
 opacity: 1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 background-image: none;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 text-shadow: none;
}

.carousel-control.left span {
 padding: 0;
}

.carousel-control.right span {
 padding: 0;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, 
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right, 
.carousel-control .icon-prev, 
.carousel-control .icon-next {
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 z-index: 5;
 display: inline-block;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .icon-prev {
 left: 30px;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right,
.carousel-control .icon-next {
 right: 30px;
}



.carousel-control.left span:hover,
.carousel-control.right span:hover {
 opacity: .7;
 filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}

.carousel-inner > .item {
  margin-left:0;
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:0;
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left:0;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.header-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 1.8%;
    right: auto;
    width: 96.66666666666666%;
    color: #fff;
}

.header-text h2 {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.header-text h2 span {
 padding: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header-text h3 span {
 color: #fff;
}

.btn-min-block {
    min-width: 170px;
    line-height: 26px;
}

.btn-theme {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.btn-theme:hover {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
}

.service-box {
 background: #fff;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #f7f7f7;
 padding: 40px 20px;
}

.service-box:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
 margin-top: -20px;
}

.service-icon {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
} 

.service-desc h5 {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #666;
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.service-desc .divider-header {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.item {
    margin: 10px;
}

.item img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
} 

#contact{
 background-color: #C9E4E4 ;   
 
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


.btn-lg,
.btn-group-lg > .btn {
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.input-group-addon {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}

.widget-contact {
 text-align: left;
}

.boxcol-25 {
 width: 100%;
}

.box-social {
 list-style: none;
}

.box-social li {
 width: 25%;
 float: left;
}


.box-social .social-facebook a { 
 display: block;
 background: #3873ae;
}

.sidebar .widget h5 {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.sidebar .widget {
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.widget ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin-left:0;
 padding-left:0;
}
.sidebar .widget ul li {
 margin-left:0;
 padding-left:0;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.sidebar .widget ul li a {
 color: #666;
}


.widget.widget_categories ul li:before {
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: 'Pe-icon-7-stroke';
 speak: none;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 font-variant: normal;
 text-transform: none;
 line-height: 1;
  
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 content: "\e684";
 margin-right: 10px;
}


.widget.widget_recent_post ul li figure {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 20px 0 0;
}

.widget.widget_recent_post ul li {
 margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.widget.widget_recent_post ul li:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.widget.widget_recent_post ul li h6 {
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.widget.widget_recent_post ul li span {
 font-size: 14px;
}

.widget .tagcloud a {
 padding: 4px 10px;
 color: #fff;
 display:inline-block;
 margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 border-radius: 2px;
}

.widget .tagcloud a:hover {
 color: #fff;
 background: #333;
}

footer{
 background-image: url(../img/hero-bg.jpg);
   background-position: center bottom;
   background-size: 100% auto;
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   min-height: 50vh;
  }

footer {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 50px 0 30px ;
 
}

footer p {
 color: #f8f8f8;
 font-size: 14px;
}

footer a.totop {
 color: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
footer a.totop:focus {
 outline: 0;
}

ul.footer-menu {
 list-style: none;
}

ul.footer-menu li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0 0 0 10px;

}

ul.footer-menu li a {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding-left: 9px;
 line-height: 1.1em;
}

ul.footer-menu li:first-child a {
 border-left: none;
 padding-left: 0;
}

.social-widget {
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.social-widget ul li a:hover {
 color: #fff;
}

footer .social-widget ul.team-social li a {
 margin: 0 5px;
}

.testimonialslide {
 margin-top:0;
 padding-top: 0;
}

.testimonialslide ul li blockquote {
 color: #fff;
 border-left: none;
}

.testimonialslide ul li h4 {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 900;
}
.testimonialslide ul li h4 span {
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.btn {
 border-radius: 2px;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
 outline: none;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-weight: 400; 
 text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
 font-size: 14px;
}

.btn.btn-noradius {
 border-radius: 0;
}

a.btn:focus{
 outline: 0;
}

.btn-red {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #c83539;
  border-color: #c83539;
}
.btn-red:hover,
.btn-red:focus,
.btn-red:active,
.btn-red.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666;
  border-color: #666;
}
.btn-red:active {
  background-image: none;
}


.btn-skin:hover,
.btn-skin:focus,
.btn-skin:active,
.btn-skin.active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #666;
  border-color: #666;
}


.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
    border: 1px solid #28c3ab;
    outline: 0;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #28c3ab;
}

.btn-huge {
    padding: 25px;
    font-size: 26px;
}

.banner-social-buttons {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.progress {
  height: 40px;

}
.progress-bar {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 40px;
}


@media(min-width:767px) {

    .navbar {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        background: 0 0;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #000;
    }

    .navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    }
 
    .intro {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .brand-heading {
        font-size: 100px;
    }
 

    .intro-text {
        font-size: 25px;
    }

}
@media (max-width:768px) {
 #navigation {
  padding: 20px 0;
 }
 .site-logo{
  margin: 0 0 0 30px;
  float:none;
 }
 .navbar-custom ul.nav li a {
  color: #eee;
 }
 .navbar-custom ul.nav ul.dropdown-menu li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;

 }
 .navbar-header {
  margin-top:-40px;
  padding:0;
 }
 .navbar-header button {
  background: #111;
 }
 
 .navbar-header button.navbar-toggle {
  padding: 4px 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
 }
 
 .navbar-custom .nav {
  background: #444;
 }
 
 .service-box {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
 }
 
 .team-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
 
 form#contact-form {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
 }
 
 .xs-marginbot-20 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
 }

}

@media (max-width:480px) {

 .navbar-custom .nav.navbar-nav {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.4);
 }
 
 .navbar.navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
 }
}

.navbar .navbar-custom {
 padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.ico">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/logo.ico" />
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">
 <title>Agrochema</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body id="page-top" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar-custom">

 <section class="hero" id="intro">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-right navicon">
     <a id="nav-toggle" class="nav_slide_button" href="#">
      <span></span>
     </a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center">
     <img src="img/logo1.png">>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center inner">
     <div class="animatedParent">
      <h1 class="animated fadeInDown">Se</h1>
      <p class="animated fadeInUp">Desbrozamo</p>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <div id="navigation">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="site-logo">
       <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" />
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-10">

      <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
       </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active">
         <a href="#intro">Casa</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#about">Sobre mi</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="#service">Servicios</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="galerias.html">Trabajos</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="form/formpage.html">Precios</a>
        </li>
        <li>
         <a href="form/formpage.html#works">Contacto</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </div>>
 <section id="about" class="home-section color-dark bg-white">
  <div class="container marginbot-50">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
     <div class="animatedParent">
      <div class="section-heading text-center animated bounceInDown">
       <h2 class="h-bold">¿Quien somos...?</h2>
       <div class="divider-header"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 animatedParent">
     <div class="text-center">
      <p>Agrochema es </p>
 <p>fit.</p>
<p>Reali</p>    

     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section id="service" class="home-section color-dark bg-gray">
  <div class="container marginbot-50">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
     <div>
      <div class="section-heading text-center">
       <h2 class="h-bold">¿Què hacemos en Agrochema...?</h2>
       <div class="divider-header"></div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row animatedParent">
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <div class="animated rotateInDownLeft">
       <div class="service-box">
        <img src="img/desbro1.png">
        <div class="service-desc">
         <p>Desbrozamos </p>      
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-skin">Nuestro</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <div class="animated rotateInDownLeft">
       <div class="service-box">
        <div class="service-desc">
         <img src="img/podas1.png">
         <p>Poda profesional p</p>
         <a href="galerias.html#service" class="btn btn-skin">Nuestro</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <div class="animated rotateInDownRight slow">
       <div class="service-box">
        <div class="service-desc">
         <img src="">
         <p>Todo</p>     
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-skin">Nues.</a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
      <div class="animated rotateInDownRight slower">
       <div class="service-box">
        <div class="service-desc">
         <img src="img/lena1.png">
         <p> Venta </p>    
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-skin">Nuestro </a>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section id="works" class="home-section color-dark text-center bg-white">
  <div class="container marginbot-50">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
     <div>
      <div class="animatedParent">
       <div class="section-heading text-center">
        <h2 class="h-bold animatedbounceInDown">Algunos</h2>
        <div class="divider-header"></div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row animatedParent">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
     <div class="row gallery-item">
      <div class="col-md-3 animated fadeInUp">
       <a href="" title="" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="">
        <img src="i" class="img-responsive" alt="img">
       </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 animated fadeInUp slow">
       <a href="img" title="" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="img/works/1@2x.jpg">
        <img src="img/" class="img-responsive" alt="img">
       </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 animated fadeInUp slower">
       <a href="i" title="" data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="img/works/1@2x.jpg">
        <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="img">
       </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 animated fadeInUp">
       <a href="i" title="." data-lightbox-gallery="gallery1" data-lightbox-hidpi="img/works/1@2x.jpg">
        <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="img">
       </a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section id="contact" class="home-section nopadd-bot color-dark bg-gray text-center">
  <div class="container marginbot-50">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
     <div class="animatedParent">
      <div class="section-heading text-center">
       <h2 class="h-bold animated bounceInDown"> con sus amigos</h2>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="FSContainer">
   <div class="FSShareAction FSmall">
    <ul>
     <li>
      <span class="FSShareBtn Facebook" data-count="0" data-social="fb">
       <svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
        <path d=""/>      
       </svg>
       <span>Share on
        <abbr>Facebook</abbr>
       </span>
      </span>
     </li>
     <li>
      <span class="FSShareBtn Twitter" data-count="0" data-social="tw">
       <svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
        <path d="#"
        />
       </svg>
       <span>Share on
        <abbr>Twitter</abbr>
       </span>
      </span>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <footer>
  <div id="container">
   <div class="column col-md-4">
    <figure>
     <img src="img/logo1.png" alt="">
    </figure>
    <p class="title4">Calle Almanzor, 11
     <br>05400 Arenas de San Pedro, Ávila
     <br>Tlf:690 85 54 30</p>
    <!--<hr class="line1">-->
    <a href="mailto:chema@agrochema.es" class="btn-link btn-link3">
     <span></span>chema@agrochema.es</a>
   </div>
   <div class="column col-md-4">
    <div class="makina">
     <img src="img/desbro-izquierda.gif">
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="column col-md-4">
    <figure>
     <img src="img/logo1.png" alt="">
    </figure>
    <p class="title4">Calle Almanzor, 11
     <br>05400 
     <br>Tlf:690</p>
    <a href="mailto:chema@agrochema.es" class="btn-link btn-link3">
     <span></span>c</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </footer>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Estuve viendo en mi teléfono y la barra si esta ahí lo que pasa es que el ancho esta fijo(al parecer) deberías colocar el css para ayudarte con esta parte

Comment: Por favor, crea un [mcve] en la propia pregunta. Los usuarios no deberían tener que visitar un sitio externo para poder ver el problema.

Comment: He puesto algo de css, pero es que no entra todo @YoAlbert No se si te servira de algo.

Comment: Gracias @AlvaroMontoro , pero si puse eso es porque no tengo otra forma de hacerlo. Como vas a ver el error si no es probando y viendo....

Comment: @MiguelEspeso Gracias por añadir parte el código que faltaba. El problema es que cuando corrijas el error en producción (y borres tu página temporal), se corregirá en la página enlazada y la pregunta dejará de tener sentido porque no habrá error que ver. Por eso es mejor que las preguntas sean autónomas e autosuficientes.

Comment: Gracias por aclaracion, ya entiendo y tienes toda la razon. Pero es que no se como hacer para que puedan ayudarme, el codigo es muy extenso la opcion que pense, fue que viendo el error seria mejor. Pero como dices cuando quite la pagina no se vera. Si consigo arreglarlo, lo que hare será ponerlo en la pregunta.Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que la navegación queda por detrás de las secciones. Esto ocurre porque:

1. Las secciones tienen definido `position` que la navegación no tiene
2. Las secciones tienen definido `z-index` (de al menos 120)

Entonces la solución es hacer que la navegación también esté posicionada y que tenga un valor de `z-index` mayor que el de las secciones. Añade el siguiente código y se solucionará el problema:

```
div#navigation-sticky-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 121;
}
```

Comment: Perdon por la tardar en responder, tuve que salir. Gracias @Alvaro Montoro .Funciona perfectamente. ¿ Que me sugieres que ponga en la pregunta para que le pueda servir a otro..? Quizá la edito entera explicando con más detalles el problema...